How is memory allocated in my union of double and bit-fields struct?
I have a union of a double and a struct of bit fields:
union byte_real {
    double db;
    struct {
        unsigned long long int mant : 52;
        unsigned int exp : 11;
        unsigned int sgn : 1;
    };
};

It was designed to divide a 64-bit double to 52 bits of mantissa, 11 bits of exponent and a bit of sign. When I loaded 1.5 to db, I expected the distribution of data to be like:
mant = 0d1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 2251799813685248
exp = 0d01111111111 = 1023
sgn = 0d0 = 0

But what they really were (values from the debugger):
mant    2251799813685248    unsigned __int64
exp     1228                unsigned int
sgn     1                   unsigned int

So, only mantissa matched. What is wrong with the way I used bit fields?

Don't use union for that in C++, it is UB.

bitfield is implementation specific, I suspect that your anonymous structure is bigger that what you expect.

@CodeGeneratorMKM  For this bit-field unsigned long long int mant : 52; the compiler allocates memory of the size sizeof( unsigned long long ) that is equal to 64 bits

@CodeGeneratorMKM At least the last two bit-fields also should have the type specifier unsigned long long int.

Do the shift yourself Demo

See also Struct alignment with bit-fields. (Maybe close enough to be a duplicate?)

Your code has multiple issues:
bitfields do not do what you think they do, and even more the way they are layed out in memory is "implementation defined" and my differ from compiler to compiler.
And read this Is it allowed to use unions for type punning, and if not, why?


How is memory allocated in my union of double and bit-fields struct?

As already commented, bitfield layout is implementation defined.
Specifically [cppref]

Adjacent bit-field members may (or may not) be packed to share and straddle the individual bytes.

GCC currently believes your union is 8 bytes.  MSVC believes the same union is 16 bytes.

What is wrong with the way I used bit fields?

Using bit-fields for this purpose is wrong.  You should use a function that manually copies the data to an integer type and inspects the appropriate bits.
This would also prevent the Undefined Behavior that results from reading a union member that wasn't most recently written to.
